# How to find the value of a dropdownlist using FindControl?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop, drop-down-menu, findcontrol

I am working on a website with VB.NET and ASP.NET. I currently have recurring DropDownLists for the user to provide input.

The design is recurring. These DropDownLists get their values from a database table, Everything with the Web interface is working except for writing these recurring values to the database - that is just to give you some background.

I have set the ID's of each DropDownList like so:

```
FrequencyList.ID = String.Concat("FreqList", DBReader(0))
```

That is in a loop while reading the DatabaseReader.

This is what I'm having issues with (please note I simplified the code down to make it easier to read:

```
    Dim i As Integer
    DBCommand = New SqlCommand()

    DBCommand.Connection = DBConnection
    DBCommand.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    DBCommand.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName"
    DBConnection.Open()
    For i = 1 To AspectTableLength


        Dim ParamFrequencyID As SqlParameter = DBCommand.Parameters.Add("@nFrequencyID", SqlDbType.Int)
        ParamFrequencyID.Value = FindControl("FreqList" & Convert.ToString(i))
        ParamFrequencyID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    Next
```

The `FindControl("FreqList" & Convert.ToString(i))` variable is incorrect because it does not access the value - and adding `.SelectedItem.Value` does not work.

Comment: So FrequencyList is a dropdownlist which has only one selected value, honestly I don't know what are you trying to accomplish, the user gets a list and then he selects one value...

Comment: @kblok - I just updated question - Frequency list is created several times, as FreqList1, FreqList2, FreqList3, up to like 50. The user has to enter this data 50 times and I need to read the data from each of these things. I found that FindControl is what I'm looking for, but I can't seem to figure out the rest.

Comment: Cool much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from a developer.

```
Dim MyControls As ControlCollection = Panel.Controls
        Dim Number As Integer 'this is the same as "DBReader(0)"

        For Each MyControl As Control In MyControls
            If MyControl.ID Is Nothing Then
            Else
                If MyControl.ID.StartsWith("Span") Then
                    Number = Replace(MyControl.ID, "Span", "")
                    Dim Freq As DropDownList = PanelMain.FindControl(“FreqList” & Number)

                    Dim ParamFrequencyID As SqlParameter = DBCommand.Parameters.Add("@nFrequencyID", SqlDbType.Int)
                    ParamFrequencyID.Value = Freq.SelectedIndex
                    ParamFrequencyID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input

                    DBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    DBCommand.Parameters.Clear()
                End If
            End If
        Next

        DBConnection.Close()
```